# what does th expression [1 : 2^nR] mesn in information theory?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-physics, information-theory

I find the below expression a lot in math, statistics and information theory `m ∈ [1 : 2^nR]`

expression is a text like the following:
`a randomized encoder that generates a codeword X^n(m), m ∈ [1 : 2nR], according to a conditional pmf p(x^n|m)`

Could some one explain it for me ?

Comment: Without a reference, I don't think so.  If you forced a guess, I'd say the interval $[1,2^nR]$ where $n$ and $R$ are suitable constants.

Comment: see page 9 (4.2.1 For zero error probability)    http://www.ece.tufts.edu/ee/194NIT/lect02.pdf

Comment: I don't see `[1:2^nR]` anywhere in the supplied reference.  I do see $(2^{nR},n)$ and $\{1, 2, \cdots, 2^{nR}\}$.

Comment: yes, thay are the same things.

Comment: What are the same things?  The two terms I posted are different.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $(M,n)=(2^{nR},n)$ usually represents a binary code (not necessarily linear) with codewords of length $n$ and rate $R\in(0,1)$ which gives (up to a floor function) $2^{nR}$ codewords. Since we're interested in asymptotics we don't care about the floor function.

The codewords can be arranged so that they correspond to one of $2^{nR}$ messages with index $\{1,2,\ldots,2^{nR}\}$